# Kiwi produces huge initramfs

Tags: initramfs

I'm using Kiwi to build a boot CD based on OpenSUSE 13.1. I want the disk ISO image to be as tiny as possible. I managed to get the read-only filesystem down to only 100MB, but for reasons unknown, the `initrd` file is 80MB on its own. (!!)

1. Is there some way I can convince Kiwi to produce a smaller initrd?
2. Is there a way to take the initrd image that Kiwi has produced and shrink it somehow?

PS. The `initrd` file is actually an initramfs image. But you probably knew that..

---

Possibly relevant: If I unpack `initrd`, I get the following:

```
# du -d1 -h .
12K     ./root
4.0K    ./selinux
4.0K    ./tmp
20K     ./run
4.0K    ./mnt
304K    ./image
16K     ./boot
8.8M    ./etc
760K    ./var
4.0K    ./sys
4.0K    ./proc
8.0K    ./dev
1.1M    ./bin
97M     ./usr
4.0K    ./opt
1.7M    ./sbin
88M     ./lib
198M    .
```